# Unable to run Excel VSTO Add-ins

Tags: asp.net, excel, visual-studio-2013, vsto, excel-addins

Trying to run an Excel 2013 VSTO Add-ins project, and I keep on getting an error that says that:

> "System.Security.SecurityException: The solution cannot be installed because it is signed by a publisher whom you have not yet chosen to trust. If you trust the publisher, add the certificate to the Trusted Publisher list."

The project has a key file with signature algorithm sha256RSA and certificate issued to/by the Windows User.

Any idea how to get around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solutions from the postings [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cba58bc6-3d57-443e-9982-59d0840b15f8/trying-to-overcome-the-the-solution-cannot-be-installed-because-it-is-signed-by-a-publisher-whom?forum=vsto).

As for myself, I've developed an Excel VSTO AddIn with a self-signed untrusted certificate that is delivered by a custom Setup.exe which is then installed on machines that belong to some end-users. I have no control over these machines because the end-users just download my Setup.exe from a public website. After setup the path of the .vsto is a local file path so I don't need a web server as a host.

In my case the following code (placed in my Setup.exe) is enough to successfully trust the Excel VSTO:

```
UserInclusionList.Add(new AddInSecurityEntry(new Uri(vstoFilePath),
    "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>...</Modulus><Exponent>...</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>"));
```

The corresponding `<RSAKeyValue>` can be found in your .vsto file.