# Unable to install VSTO Addin for Outlook 2007 from an FTP server on other machines

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

While trying to install on other machines I get the following exceptions:

```
[12:22:33] Shekhar Pandey: Name: OutlookAddIn1
From: https://www.emailcipher.com/outlook/OutlookAddIn1.vsto

Exception Text 
System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for OutlookAddIn1 or its location is not trusted. Contact your administrator for further assistance.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustPromptKeyInternal(ClickOnceTrustPromptKeyValue promptKeyValue, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String productName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustUsingPromptKey(Uri manifest, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String productName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySecurity(ActivationContext context, Uri manifest, AddInInstallationStatus installState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

[12:22:48] Shekhar Pandey:

Exception Text 
System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for OutlookAddIn1 or its location is not trusted. Contact your administrator for further assistance.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustPromptKeyInternal(ClickOnceTrustPromptKeyValue promptKeyValue, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String productName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustUsingPromptKey(Uri manifest, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String productName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySecurity(ActivationContext context, Uri manifest, AddInInstallationStatus installState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer
```

The URL of the deployment manifest is: https://www.emailcipher.com/outlook/OutlookAddIn1.vsto

How can I enable the deployment of my VSTO Addin?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your deployment manifest I assume that your certificate with the identity `CN=Abc\Dell` is not signed with Authenticode and that you use the posted URL to deploy it to the other machines. (But I'm not 100% sure about the latter because you say `ftp` in the title but `https` in the posted URL.)

First you have to add your URL on the client machines to the `Trusted sites` list using [the options here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-do-i-add-a-site-to-my-trusted-sites-list/98cc77c8-b364-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5). You can check this by opening your .vsto in Internet Explorer and looking at the page properties. `Zone` should now be `Trusted sites` and not `Internet`. If you cannot change the `Trusted sites` list you can alternatively add your URL to the `Local intranet` zone as well.

If it still fails with the same error message you have to add your certificate to the `Trusted Publishers` on the client machine using [the commands here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172241.aspx). If you don't want to use the command line you can do the same [in the GUI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754431(v=ws.11).aspx) using the `Certificates` snap-in in the `MMC` or using [the method here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx#clickoncetrustpub_topic4). If you don't have the permission to add a certificate to the `Trusted Publishers` because a Group Policy of the client domain is restricting the access then you also have to check [the Group Policy settings here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733026(v=ws.11).aspx).

If your client is using a Windows Server OS you may also have to deactivate the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration (IEESC) using [the settings here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chenley/2011/03/10/how-to-turn-off-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration/). (At least for the duration of the deployment.)

At last you can also check the registry for the settings of the Inclusion Lists using [the registry keys here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772070.aspx).

I guess that adding your URL to the `Trusted sites` should be enough to make your VSTO deployment work. If it isn't, adding your certificate to the `Trusted Publishers` will most likely do the trick.

Comment: So I need to make changes on every client machine that will install my plugin. Is there any other way

Comment: https://www.emailcipher.com/outlook/setup.exe this is the link to my plugin please check it in your system too

Comment: @SonikaSood If you have an own Setup.exe that deploys your VSTO then it's a bit easier than pure ClickOnce deployment. You can use this code to add your certificate to the Inclusion List during the installation process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025720/unable-to-run-excel-vsto-add-ins/40042872#40042872 This should be enough to successfully enable the trust of your VSTO - at least if Setup.exe deploys your manifest to a local path. (I'm using the same code in my own Setup.exe deploying an Excel VSTO Addin.)

Comment: i m not having my own setup.exe. what if i purchase one code signing https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/code-signing-dual-signing-sha256-sha1.htm through this

Comment: @SonikaSood Yes, [according to here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/isrpfeplat/2011/11/06/authenticode-signing-vstos-and-what-they-have-to-do-with-crls/) signing your VSTO addin with an Authenticode certificate is enough to enable the trust. (Scroll down a bit to the VSTO part of the article.) Additionally take a look at [this information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172240.aspx). Regarding digicert: I don't know them in particular but at first glance that link certainly looks good.

Comment: Just an FYI - I have bought the DigiCert EV Code Signing Certificate and for VSTO applications it does NOT work. I still get the same "not trusted" issue...